# How to do a proper Linux server backup to store apps installed and configurations?

Tags: linux, backup

I am familiar with using rsync for backups on Linux. However, in the event of a hard disk crash, I have been repeatedly told that with a new disk, install a latest version of the OS, then the data created (word processing files, accounting, etc.) then you are back to normal. However, what about all the configuration files stored in /etc and elsewhere? What about the applications I installed which were not part of a yum repo? I don't believe they can simply be copied back over a new installation or on different hardware without overwriting needs files by the OS?

I would greatly appreciate and kind and thoughtful reply to this, because this problem truly bothers me. I don't want to spend a day or two rebuilding a system by trying to remember which configurations need to be changed, cron jobs, applications installed, scripts, etc.

In addition, how do a document what has been installed on a Linux server? Sometimes you install a script, works great, and easily forget it was there. What should the method be? Create a "logbook" of all changes done to the server including each application? Sounds like there needs to be a better method.

Or should I not be using rsync for full backups like this, and look at something else which might do a bare metal store? Thanks in advance for your helpful reply!

Comment: The log book method is the way we do it, actually. In SQL Server circles, we call it a "run book" and it's a detailed description of the configuration of the server. In other words, a detailed guide of the disaster recovery process, from bare metal to data recovery. For what it's worth, you'd probably do well with a "base install" recovery, plus differential backups.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Randolph. Can you share the format of your "run book"? What is in it, besides I assume date and action? Also, do you keep the "run book" on a different file server or another place? Thank you!

Comment: I've posted an answer for you with more detail.

Comment: If you made backups of the full filesystem, then you can simply restore that to a newly formatted disk and make it bootable. Has worked perfectly fine for me numerous times.

Answer (score 2):

I use a run book, based on this old Microsoft [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917702.aspx) for SQL Server 2000.

> **Contents of a Run Book**
>
> A run book should contain all of the information you and your staff
> need to perform day-to-day operations and to respond to emergency
> situations. This information should include the following:
>
> - Resource information about the data center and its hardware and
>   software
> - Process information, including step-by-step procedures for operational
>   and emergency processes
>
> The run book should contain all necessary information to enable a
> staff member to perform any process, from performing a backup to
> failing over to a remote site.

Comment: Since I've been doing this a while, my version is quite heavily modified, but this is where I started.

Comment: Thank you, Randolph! Excellent resource to start with. This also hopefully avoids panic situations in an emergency as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use two strategies, depending on time, space and resources:

1) Physically mirror the disk (drop to single user mode and "cp /dev/sda /dev/sdb") and keep the drive somewhere else.

2) I use [Mondo Rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/) which creates bootable restore images which rebuilds the system back to the same state is was when I ran the backup.

Method (2) is faster for large drives that are not full of data. (1) is more reliable if the drives are identical.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I maintain a run book as an OpenOffice document in an easily locatable location in my home directory. In there I document the scripts and tools that I customise, including command-line parameters, download URLs, etc. On other systems that I support, I use the same idea, and pass on the document to incoming sysadmins.